# Software to rename multiple files in ascending numerical order regardless of file type?

Tags: windows, file-search, rename

I want to take all my iphone images and videos and back them up in my google drive. I have all the files in chronological order, but there are gaps between most of their file numbers because I delete a lot of photos/videos. So I want to rename my files: IMG_(1), IMG_(...).

I can do this easily with the options Windows has, by getting the files in the order I want them, selecting them all, and renaming the first file. But the system discriminates between file types when doing this, so I end up with all the image files numbered separately from video files. I end up with things like, "IMG_(2451) IMG_(61) IMG_(2452)". So the original point of renaming -- being able to simply click and organize by file name while maintaining chronological order and not having to click on date created -- is lost.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeCommander will do exactly what you want.

It is available here: https://freecommander.com/

FreeCommander is very powerful and will provide the functionality to assign ascending filenames to each file, regardless of file type.

This functionality is available under the `File` menu, and is called `Multi-Rename`.

That's just the tip of the iceberg for FreeCommander.  Its ***multi-rename*** functionality is truly outstanding.

---

Update: After losing important data due to FreeCommander bugs, I can no longer recommend this application.  The developer simply does not perform adequate testing before releases, and does not have any dedicated QA testers.  I do still think its renaming tool is excellent, and I have never lost any data using it, so I can still recommend its integrated renamer for your use, but overall the project needs a much higher level of QC to recommend it universally.